# Do methods call retain on arguments when they get called?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, methods, concurrent-programming

If I call a method in Objective-C with an argument and releasing the argument afterwords.

```
id argumentI = [Object new]; 
[ classA method1: argumentI ];
[ argumentI release ];
```

Then I know the argument is released AFTER method1 is finished, because the lines are processed linear.
BUT when I call the method in a background thread:

```
[ NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method1) toTarget:self withObject:argumentI ];
[ argumentI release ];
```

And then the main thread releases the object, WHILE the background job uses the argument for something
(With the acceptance, that the retainCount would be 1 before the method is called).
Could I get an Error, because of the use of a Zombie (use of an object, that is already deallocated)?

The question is:

Do the methods call retain on an object that is an argument? Or do I need to call retain at the beginning of the method, if it is like the problem above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CHDEBGEC) of `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`

> The objects aTarget and anArgument are retained during the execution of the detached thread, then released.

Comment: So the answer to the questions posed by the OP are “No” and “No” respectively, because as you point out `-detachNewThreadSelector:` explicitly retains the target and argument during thread execution.